# WebRTC and won't play GarageBand manipulated sound after redirected with sound flower. Only not working in chrome

Tags: webrtc, audio-streaming, simplewebrtc, mediastream

I am writing a web based app the requires real time audio manipulation, specifically a pitch shift in a users voice. For now my prototype uses GarageBand to pitch shift and soundflower to redirect the audio as my input audio source on the browser. Then using webRTC (simple webRTC library)I send a users web cam video and the manipulated webRTC stream to other browsers. This works great in Firefox but I have not had luck with chrome. The video channel is received fine but the audio is only silent on chrome. Any ideas ?